# Show that no values of $k$ can make curve intersect the line

Tags: functions, curves

The actual question is:

> Show that there are no values of $k$ for which the line $y=3-2x$ can intersect the curve $y=2x^2+kx+3$.
>   My approach was:

$$2x^2+kx+3=3-2x\\
\implies2x^2+(k+2)x=0$$

Now no values of k can make $y=3-2x$ intersect $y=2x^2+kx+3$ means

$$(k+2)^2-4\cdot2\cdot0<0$$

or, $(k+2)(k+2)<0$

So there are no values for $k$.

But

If i plot the graph of $y=2x^2-2x+3=0$ and $y=3-2x$, where $k=-2$ then i see
them intersect at $(0,3)$ as i also get $(0,3)$ by solving simultaneously.

I cannot get what was the problem in the method of solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminant of $$2x^2+(k+2)x$$ is equal to $$(k+2)^2$$ which is always positive. This is why the equation $$2x^2+(k+2)x = 0$$ always has at least one solution (i.e., $x=0$), and if $k\neq -2$, then it has two distinct solutions (the other one being $-\frac{2}{k+2}$)

Comment: So should the question be clearly saying if k>0, k can never make line intersect the curve?

Comment: @Amar30657 no, the answer is that no matter what $k$ is equal to, the line **always** intersects the curve.

Comment: Show that there are no values of k for which the line cannot intersect the curve ? Is that to be the question because question says us to show it can never intersect but we find it alwasys so this question right?

Comment: @Amar30657 Well sure, the question must either have a typo or you misunderstand it. The fact is that the curve $y=3-2x$ **always** intersects $$y=2x^2+kx+3$$ at $(0,3)$.

Answer (score 5):

With $x=0$
$2x^2+kx+3=3$
$3-2x=3$

So $(0,3)$ is an intersection.

So any $k$ yields at least one intersection, and so your method of solving is not wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The equation $2x^2+(k+2)x=0$ has a solution $x=0$ for every $k$. Therefore, it is not amazing the the curves do intersect when $x=0$.